# How can I solve a display issue with Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: display, 21.04

When I installed ubuntu 21.04 on my system the display went all to pot.  It throws pixels randomly across the screen (digital snow) and occasionally puts random colors out.  My monitor is an AOC 2219S-1 and my graphics card is a GEFORCE 210 Nvidia.  It appears as though my drivers are incompatible with the new OS.  The new OS is unable to install the recommended drivers.
Does anybody have any suggestions?  Must I re-install an older OS?

Answer (score 0):

Start `Software & Updates` and select the **Additional Drivers** tab, and see if your Nvidia 210 drivers are there...

[image]

Or, go to https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/ and download this driver for your Nvidia 210 card...

[image]

[image]

**Update #1:**

See the installation instructions at http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.108/README/installdriver.html

Comment: No additional drivers are available and NVIDIA site has not drivers that will download with Ubuntu 21.04!

Comment: @Office If you go to the link that I provided, and select the details of your video card from the popup buttons, you'll find the download for Linux/Ubuntu. I'll quickly update my answer for you...

Comment: I went to that site earlier and there was no listing for my driver.  However, by rebooting in a Ubuntu repair mode, my problem seems to have been solved.  I'll keep my fingers crossed!!  Thank you for your response.  As a newbie, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Office Booting in Ubuntu "repair" mode isn't a normal way to run a system. When you go to the website that I gave the link for, and enter the values that I show, aren't you getting the same driver info that I'm getting?

Comment: When I go to that website, there is no listing for the video card that I have (GeForce 210 GT218).  So I do not see how you are getting a driver.  Am I not seeing something that you are?When I try the automatic driver updates on that page, I cannot open the ,exe file that it downloads to me.  You are correct, the repair mode is a poor choice since the system reverts to the problem condition whenever I reboot it!  I am ready to try to revert to my old version of Ubuntu but I don't know how to save all of my data in a recoverable way.

Comment: @Office No, you don't use the automatic driver download on that web page. You use the manual search, and enter the values that I show. Then you'll get the driver. Once installed, your problem may be fixed, so no need to backup and revert.

Comment: I couldn't find the listing you show for my model 210 card, but I downloaded the driver you show in your screen shot and when I click on it to run it my system tries to read it instead of run it and I get the comment that "the document is not UTF-8 valid".  How can I run it instead or just read it?

Comment: @Office I don't know why you're having such a problem finding this using the manual search function. Just fill out the boxes like I show, and click the Start Search button. See the install instructions at http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.108/README/installdriver.html

Comment: @Office Status please...